# why label in view get data from controller is null

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2

i have write code in controller launch function .get data from store,and use Ext.each to get string in records,and use setdata to pass string type data to make label display . if i write static string it work, but it dont work when i pass string from records + describe string.

code in controller launch funtion

```
storeId.load({
        callback: function(records, operation, success){
            Ext.each(records, function(record) {
                console.log(record.get('data'));
                console.log(record.get('earn'));                    
                var data = record.get('data');                        
                var string = '{data:\'' + record.get('data') + '\',earn:\'' + record.get('earn') + '\'}';
                console.log(string);
            //Ext.getCmp('datalabel').setData({data: '10000',earn: '10000'});----work
            Ext.getCmp('datalabel').setData(string);-----not work display null
            });
        }
    });
```

code in view

```
                        xtype: 'label',
                        id: 'datalabel',
                        flex: 1,
                        store: 'datainterests',
                        tpl: 'money：{data},interests：{earn}',
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works prove that `setData()` apply object type argument instead of string.

```
Ext.getCmp('datalabel').setData({data: '10000',earn: '10000'});
```

You may try :

```
Ext.getCmp('datalabel').setData({
    data: record.get('data'),
    earn: record.get('earn')
});
```

or

```
Ext.getCmp('datalabel').setData(record.raw);
```